# Formatting a file for sendmail

Tags: linux, unix, sendmail

How can I format a file so I can just do `cat file | sendmail`?

By putting `Subject: This is the subject`, I don't need to specify the subject in sendmail, but adding the `To: myemail@hostname.com` field gives me `Recipient names must be specified`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the distinction between message *contents* (headers and body) and message *envelope*.  You're invoking `sendmail` with message contents, but you aren't supplying the envelope.  It's the envelope that controls delivery.  Without it, the message cannot go anywhere.

You don't say *which* `sendmail` command that you are using.  Each MTS — Sendmail, qmail, Postfix, exim, and so forth — has its own.  The common subset of them all has just two ways of specifying envelope sender and envelope recipients:

- explicitly on the command line as arguments to `sendmail`:

  ```
  < file sendmail -f Steven.Morad@example.org postmaster@localhost
  ```
- implicitly in the message body, which is parsed for `To:`, `Cc:`, and `Bcc:` headers:

  ```
  < file sendmail -f Steven.Morad@example.org -t
  ```

This common subset is very limited.  Observe, for example, that this mode of message submission from standard input and command arguments is Sendmail's `-bm` mode, but not all `sendmail` programs actually even support a `-bm` option.  So to portably invoke this mode, you cannot use the option.

There are also portability caveats when combining `-t` with recipients given as command arguments, for the details of which see Dave Sill's book.  So pick one form or the other.  Don't mix them.

### Further reading

- Dave Sill (2001). "`sendmail` injection".  *The qmail Handbook*.  ISBN 9781893115408.  Apress.  pp. 123–126.
- Weitse Venema.  [*`sendmail`*](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html).  Postfix manual pages.
- [*`sendmail`*](http://www.courier-mta.org/sendmail.html).  Courier manual pages.
- Era Eriksson (2000).  [*The Useless Use of `cat` Award*](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Answer (score 1):

By default, `sendmail` expects the recipients to be specified on command line. Use `-t` to make it read the `To:`, `Cc:`, `Bcc:` headers.